# SQL Server : Union all & Group by clause not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table as per below detail:-

```
CREATE TABLE ITEM_DIM
(
     DOCKET_NO VARCHAR(9), 
     DOC_DT DATETIME,
     GL_CODE VARCHAR(10),
     ITEM_CD VARCHAR(15),
     ITEM_DIMENSION VARCHAR(100),
     LOT_NOS VARCHAR(15),
     QTY1 DECIMAL(14, 6), QTY2 DECIMAL(14, 6), QTY3 DECIMAL(14, 6),
     QTY4 DECIMAL(14, 6), QTY5 DECIMAL(14, 6), QTY6 DECIMAL(14, 6),
     QTY7 DECIMAL(14, 6), QTY8 DECIMAL(14, 6), QTY9 DECIMAL(14, 6),
     QTY10 DECIMAL(14, 6), QTY11 DECIMAL(14, 6), QTY12 DECIMAL(14, 6),
     QTY14 DECIMAL(14, 6), QTY15 DECIMAL(14, 6), QTY16 DECIMAL(14, 6)
)
```

Insert statements to insert data into table :-

```
INSERT INTO ITEM_DIM (DOCKET_NO, DOC_DT, GL_CODE, ITEM_CD, ITEM_DIMENSION, 
                      LOT_NOS, QTY1, QTY2, QTY3, QTY4, QTY5, QTY6, QTY7, QTY8) 
VALUES ('ZKR000816', '2016-08-20', 'PARTY0002', '1285BRF21OP', 'INNER DIA', 
        'AA8/ZZ16', 40.1, 40, 39.91, 39.92, 39.93, 39.94, 39.95, 39.96),
       ('ZKR000816', '2016-08-20', 'PARTY0002', '1285BRF21OP', 'INNER DIA 1', 
        'AA8/ZZ16', 37.8, 37.71, 37.72, 37.73, 37.74, 37.75, 37.76, 37.77),
       ('ZKR000816', '2016-08-20', 'PARTY0002', '1285BRF21OP', 'THICKNESS', 
        'AA8/ZZ16', 0.88, 0.72, 0.73, 0.74, 0.75, 0.76, 0.77, 0.77),
       ('ZKR000816', '2016-08-20', 'PARTY0002', '1285BRF21OP', 'THICKNESS 1', 
        'AA8/ZZ16', 0.71, 0.72, 0.73, 0.74, 0.75, 0.76, 0.77, 0.78)
```

Select statement to display data :-

```
SELECT 
    DOCKET_NO, DOC_DT, GL_CODE, PARTY_CD, ITEM_CD, ITEM_DIMENSION, LOT_NOS,
    QTY1, QTY2, QTY3, QTY4, QTY5, QTY6, QTY7, QTY8 
FROM 
    ITEM_DIM
```

I'm trying to get result as per attached image "desired result":

[image]

So I write below query to get desired result:

```
SELECT 
    DOC_DT, PARTY_CD, ITEM_CD, LOT_NOS, INNER_DIA, THK 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         DOC_DT, GL_CODE, PARTY_CD, ITEM_CD, LOT_NOS, QTY1, INNER_DIA, 0 THK 
     FROM ITEM_DIM
     WHERE ITEM_DIMENSION IN ('INNER DIA','INNER DIA 1')
     UNION ALL
SELECT DOC_DT,GL_CODE PARTY_CD,ITEM_CD,LOT_NOS,QTY2 INNER_DIA,0 THK FROM ITEM_DIM
WHERE ITEM_DIMENSION IN ('INNER DIA','INNER DIA 1')
UNION ALL
SELECT DOC_DT,GL_CODE PARTY_CD,ITEM_CD,LOT_NOS,QTY3 INNER_DIA,0 THK FROM ITEM_DIM
WHERE ITEM_DIMENSION IN ('INNER DIA','INNER DIA 1')
UNION ALL
SELECT DOC_DT,GL_CODE PARTY_CD,ITEM_CD,LOT_NOS,QTY4 INNER_DIA,0 THK FROM ITEM_DIM
WHERE ITEM_DIMENSION IN ('INNER DIA','INNER DIA 1')
UNION ALL
SELECT DOC_DT,GL_CODE PARTY_CD,ITEM_CD,LOT_NOS,QTY5 INNER_DIA,0 THK FROM ITEM_DIM
WHERE ITEM_DIMENSION IN ('INNER DIA','INNER DIA 1')
UNION ALL
SELECT DOC_DT,GL_CODE PARTY_CD,ITEM_CD,LOT_NOS,QTY6 INNER_DIA,0 THK FROM ITEM_DIM
WHERE ITEM_DIMENSION IN ('INNER DIA','INNER DIA 1')
UNION ALL
SELECT DOC_DT,GL_CODE PARTY_CD,ITEM_CD,LOT_NOS,QTY7 INNER_DIA,0 THK FROM ITEM_DIM
WHERE ITEM_DIMENSION IN ('INNER DIA','INNER DIA 1')
UNION ALL
SELECT DOC_DT,GL_CODE PARTY_CD,ITEM_CD,LOT_NOS,QTY8 INNER_DIA,0 THK FROM ITEM_DIM
WHERE ITEM_DIMENSION IN ('INNER DIA','INNER DIA 1')
UNION ALL
SELECT DOC_DT,GL_CODE PARTY_CD,ITEM_CD,LOT_NOS,0 INNER_DIA, QTY1 THK FROM ITEM_DIM
WHERE ITEM_DIMENSION IN ('THICKNESS','THICKNESS 1')
UNION ALL
SELECT DOC_DT,GL_CODE PARTY_CD,ITEM_CD,LOT_NOS,0 INNER_DIA, QTY2 THK FROM ITEM_DIM
WHERE ITEM_DIMENSION IN ('THICKNESS','THICKNESS 1')
UNION ALL
SELECT DOC_DT,GL_CODE PARTY_CD,ITEM_CD,LOT_NOS,0 INNER_DIA, QTY3 THK FROM ITEM_DIM
WHERE ITEM_DIMENSION IN ('THICKNESS','THICKNESS 1')
UNION ALL
SELECT DOC_DT,GL_CODE PARTY_CD,ITEM_CD,LOT_NOS,0 INNER_DIA, QTY4 THK FROM ITEM_DIM
WHERE ITEM_DIMENSION IN ('THICKNESS','THICKNESS 1')
UNION ALL
SELECT DOC_DT,GL_CODE PARTY_CD,ITEM_CD,LOT_NOS,0 INNER_DIA, QTY5 THK FROM ITEM_DIM
WHERE ITEM_DIMENSION IN ('THICKNESS','THICKNESS 1')
UNION ALL
SELECT DOC_DT,GL_CODE PARTY_CD,ITEM_CD,LOT_NOS,0 INNER_DIA, QTY6 THK FROM ITEM_DIM
WHERE ITEM_DIMENSION IN ('THICKNESS','THICKNESS 1')
UNION ALL
SELECT DOC_DT,GL_CODE PARTY_CD,ITEM_CD,LOT_NOS,0 INNER_DIA, QTY7 THK FROM ITEM_DIM
WHERE ITEM_DIMENSION IN ('THICKNESS','THICKNESS 1')
UNION ALL
SELECT DOC_DT,GL_CODE PARTY_CD,ITEM_CD,LOT_NOS,0 INNER_DIA, QTY8 THK FROM ITEM_DIM
WHERE ITEM_DIMENSION IN ('THICKNESS','THICKNESS 1')) Z
```

but my query displaying result as per attached image "My_Qry_Result" instead of the desired result.

[image]

I also tried joins but not getting desired data. So please help me to get the desired result - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `UNPIVOT`. Note that I changed your tables to `TEMP TABLES` for testing. Just remove the # in front of the table name.

```
CREATE TABLE #ITEM_DIM
(
     DOCKET_NO VARCHAR(9), 
     DOC_DT DATETIME,
     GL_CODE VARCHAR(10),
     ITEM_CD VARCHAR(15),
     ITEM_DIMENSION VARCHAR(100),
     LOT_NOS VARCHAR(15),
     QTY1 DECIMAL(14, 6), QTY2 DECIMAL(14, 6), QTY3 DECIMAL(14, 6),
     QTY4 DECIMAL(14, 6), QTY5 DECIMAL(14, 6), QTY6 DECIMAL(14, 6),
     QTY7 DECIMAL(14, 6), QTY8 DECIMAL(14, 6), QTY9 DECIMAL(14, 6),
     QTY10 DECIMAL(14, 6), QTY11 DECIMAL(14, 6), QTY12 DECIMAL(14, 6),
     QTY14 DECIMAL(14, 6), QTY15 DECIMAL(14, 6), QTY16 DECIMAL(14, 6)
)


INSERT INTO #ITEM_DIM (DOCKET_NO, DOC_DT, GL_CODE, ITEM_CD, ITEM_DIMENSION, 
                      LOT_NOS, QTY1, QTY2, QTY3, QTY4, QTY5, QTY6, QTY7, QTY8) 
VALUES ('ZKR000816', '2016-08-20', 'PARTY0002', '1285BRF21OP', 'INNER DIA', 
        'AA8/ZZ16', 40.1, 40, 39.91, 39.92, 39.93, 39.94, 39.95, 39.96),
       ('ZKR000816', '2016-08-20', 'PARTY0002', '1285BRF21OP', 'INNER DIA 1', 
        'AA8/ZZ16', 37.8, 37.71, 37.72, 37.73, 37.74, 37.75, 37.76, 37.77),
       ('ZKR000816', '2016-08-20', 'PARTY0002', '1285BRF21OP', 'THICKNESS', 
        'AA8/ZZ16', 0.88, 0.72, 0.73, 0.74, 0.75, 0.76, 0.77, 0.77),
       ('ZKR000816', '2016-08-20', 'PARTY0002', '1285BRF21OP', 'THICKNESS 1', 
        'AA8/ZZ16', 0.71, 0.72, 0.73, 0.74, 0.75, 0.76, 0.77, 0.78)


--First we unpivot the Diameter into a TempTable
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Diam') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Diam

select DOC_DT, GL_CODE, ITEM_CD, LOT_NOS, DIA, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DOC_DT, GL_CODE, ITEM_CD) RN
INTO #Diam
FROM
(SELECT DOC_DT, GL_CODE, ITEM_CD, LOT_NOS, QTY1, QTY2, QTY3, QTY4, QTY5, QTY6, QTY7, QTY8, QTY9, QTY10, QTY11, QTY12, QTY14, QTY15, QTY16
FROM #ITEM_DIM
WHERE ITEM_DIMENSION LIKE 'INNER DIA%') as CP
UNPIVOT
(DIA for Diams in (QTY1, QTY2, QTY3, QTY4, QTY5, QTY6, QTY7, QTY8, QTY9, QTY10, QTY11, QTY12, QTY14, QTY15, QTY16)) AS UP

--Next we unpivot the thickness into a TempTable
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Thick') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Thick

select DOC_DT, GL_CODE, ITEM_CD, LOT_NOS, THK, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DOC_DT, GL_CODE, ITEM_CD) RN
INTO #Thick
FROM
(SELECT DOC_DT, GL_CODE, ITEM_CD, LOT_NOS, QTY1, QTY2, QTY3, QTY4, QTY5, QTY6, QTY7, QTY8, QTY9, QTY10, QTY11, QTY12, QTY14, QTY15, QTY16
FROM #ITEM_DIM
WHERE ITEM_DIMENSION LIKE 'THICKNESS%') as CP
UNPIVOT
(THK for Thickness in (QTY1, QTY2, QTY3, QTY4, QTY5, QTY6, QTY7, QTY8, QTY9, QTY10, QTY11, QTY12, QTY14, QTY15, QTY16)) AS UP



--Now bring them together, based on the Row Number
SELECT
    d.DOC_DT,
    d.GL_CODE as PARTY_CD,
    d.ITEM_CD,
    d.LOT_NOS,
    d.DIA as INNER_DIA,
    t.THK
FROM #Diam d
INNER JOIN #Thick t on 
    t.RN = d.RN
```

**RESULTS BELOW. ORDER THEM HOW EVER YOU'DE LIKE**

[image]